# Problems with regenerative receiver circuit

Tags: pcb, rf, radio, receiver, regenerative

Im trying to build a regenerative receiver, that is supposed to receive a ASK/OOK modulated signal. but there are a few problems. Keep in mind this circuit might be horrendous, but it's just a proof of concept.

**Problem 1:**

The LC tank circuit is tuned to 8 MHz which in practice shall attenuate frequencies above and below the resonance, but this is not the case for my circuit. When I observe the output FFT of the circuit without any 8 MHz signal transmitted, i do se an amplitude peak in the 8 MHz range but the strongest peak is around 4 MHz. Why would this happen?

**Problem 2:**

During the testing of this circuit, it sometimes starts oscillating at around 4 MHz. I suspect this is due to the feedback from one of the BJT's, i've tried to fix this but the circuit won't function correctly if the feedback is removed.

**Filtering**

I have tried implementing a bandpass filter to remove the unwanted high amplitude low frequencies picked up by the receiver, but I have been unsuccessful. I have considered creating a crystal filter as the transmitter is a crystal based oscillator, but i could not find any simple implementation which is possible to create witout the right equipment

Circuit diagram:
[image]

Picture of the circuit:
[image]

(Some writen values on the PCB are wrong, the PCB uses the values of the circuit diagram)

Comment: I see no circuit evidence of it being a regenerative receiver. Where did you obtain the circuit?

Comment: Most any regen receiver has an adjustable control for *regeneration* - this one does not. Does the parent documentation *really* describe it as a regenerative receiver? Furthermore, the antenna tuned circuit values cannot resonate as high as 8 MHz.... for any setting of C1 capacitance.

Comment: As other comments state this is not a regenerative receiver, for that you need positive feedback.